# Do external links load slower?

Tags: html

This seems like a really simple question that I would be able to find the answer to super easily, but apparently not.

On a web page, let's say I'm loading an image. Would it take longer for the page to load if I write the link as `<img src="http://www.example.com/img/image.jpg">` than if I put it as `<img src="/image.jpg">`?

The image would be on the same site as the page. The reason I'm asking is because I have a bunch of files that use the external method, and and wondering if it's worth it to change them.

Comment: It takes _exactly_ the same amount of time. If you use the short form, the user's browser fills in the missing part and sends the same request.

Comment: On a related nore, I would really recommend that you use relative urls because that way you can use it in testing and production. Otherwise you will have to replace all the `http://dev.example.com/img.jpg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing absolute URLs and external URLs.

Using an absolute URL will cause the HTML document to take longer to load (simply because you have added more characters to its source code). It will not, however, be *significantly* longer.

The image will not take longer to load. The browser would have to resolve a relative URL into an absolute URL before using it anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Just the answer I was looking for.